# @ControllerAdvice Not Firing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I'm working on a Spring MVC/Webflow Application (version 3.2) and trying to get exception handling working where I can output a custom exception message to a logfile and error.jsp. The problem I'm having is that the Exception Handler is not getting fired. I've created the following class and annotated it "`@ControllerAdvice`" and put it into the same package as my controller that is throwing the exception:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyCustomExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleMyException(MyCustomException ex) {   
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("/error/error");
        modelAndView.addObject("errorId", ex.getErrorId());
        modelAndView.addObject("message", ex.getErrorMessage());        
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

and added the following to the mvc-config File:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

And included the following in my app-config File:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package containing my controllers and MyCustomExceptionController">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" 
    expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" />
    </context:component-scan>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: The method `handleMyException()` will only be invoked whenever an unhandled  custom exception of your choice occurs (`MyCustomException`). Is this method **not** invoked even after `MyCustomException` is thrown? [This](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-exception-handling-controlleradvice-annotation/) is the tutorial you may get closer.

Comment: I've put a breakpoint on handleMyException and the method never gets invoked even after I throw MyCustomException.

Comment: If you were to annotate a method of your choice with the `@InitBinder` annotation in this class, just as an example, was that method invoked?

Comment: Hi Tiny, I've added the following test method to the same class but it never gets invoked: @InitBinder
 public void InitBinder() {
  System.out.println("In InitBinder method");
 }

Comment: I have [this](http://pastebin.com/iYpcin96) configuration file (`dispatcher-servlet.xml`). Would you like to compare it with your config file? Apart from that I have specified `<context:annotation-config/>` in another file `applicationContext.xml` but this should not be relevant to the concrete problem you're facing. The `@ControllerAdvice` annotation works with these configurations in both Spring 3.2.2 and Spring 4.0.0 GA (**Disclaimer :** I don't know about Spring WebFlow).

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm trying to get @ControllerAdvice to fire everytime webflow throws an exception but I cannot seem to figure it out?

Answer (score 8):

The `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` element implicitly registers a `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` bean. This class has a `initExceptionHandlerAdviceCache()` method which scans beans in the context to find those whose class type is annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`.

It does this by first calling [`ControllerAdviceBean.findAnnotatedBeans(ApplicationContext)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/ControllerAdviceBean.html#findAnnotatedBeans-org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext-). Internally, this method uses [`ApplicationContext#getBeanDefinitionNames()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeanDefinitionNames--). The javadoc of this method states

> Does not consider any hierarchy this factory may participate

To clarify what this means. When you declare a `ContextLoaderListener` in your deployment descriptor, it loads what we call a root or application `ApplicationContext` and makes it available in the `ServletContext`. When you then declare a `DispatcherServlet`, it creates its own *servlet* `ApplicationContext` and uses any `ApplicationContext` it finds in the `ServletContext` attributes loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` as a parent to that context. The hierarchy looks like so

```
Root ApplicationContext // loaded by the ContextLoaderListener
            |
Servlet ApplicationContext // loaded by the DispatcherServlet
```

Every `ApplicationContext` has access to beans in parent contexts, but not the other way around.

The method above chooses not to use the beans in parent contexts and so only has access to beans in the current `ApplicationContext` (`BeanFactory` really).

As such, if your

```
<context:component-scan .../>
```

is declared in a root `ApplicationContext` as I'll assume from the name `app-config`, but the

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

is declared in the servlet `ApplicationContext`, again assuming from `mvc-config`, then the `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` looking for `@ControllerAdvice` beans will not find any. It is looking for beans in the servlet context but they aren't there, they are in the root context.

Comment: so what we should do here?

Comment: @gabby You rearrange your configuration elements noted above are together.

Comment: Great explanation but still solution is missing

Comment: According to the answer, the solution is simple - I've just moved <mvc:annotation-driven /> from mvc-config to to app-config, and everything starts working

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into a problem like this - I found an error I had.

I only had one RequestMapping (http://localhost:8080/myapp/verify/verify)

In an `InterceptorController`, in the PreHandle method, I explicitly threw an exception -> `throw new MyCustomException("error","error.jsp")` to test my `@ControllerAdvice` `Exception` handling.

When I went to http://localhost:8080/myapp/ I would see the interceptor controller get called, my custom exception get thrown, but the `@ControllerAdvice` class with my `@ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)` was never called.

I added a `@RequestMapping(value="/")` and it resolved my issues. Since I was attempting to go to a URI that had no `@RequestMapping` associated with it, i was getting a `'NoHandlerFoundException'` which was shorting out my `Exception` from bubbling up.

In short, make sure the URI you're attempting to invoke has a `@RequestMapping` associated with it, or have a method in your `ExceptionHandler` class to deal with the `NoHandlerFoundException`.

Hope this helps.