# How to implement ResponseBodyAdvice to all controllers?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, response.addheader

I have a requirement to edit my HttpResponse to add header value. I was searching for single point to implement it and found that `ResponseBodyadvice` would be helpful.

But both methods That overrode in my new class was never called. Could you please tell if I have missed any configurations.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class EditResponseHeader implements ResponseBodyAdvice<object> {


@Override
public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType,
        Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {

   return true;
}

....

@Override
public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType,
        MediaType selectedContentType,
        Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
        ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {

    ....

    return body;
}

}
```

Comment: All my controllers are having @RequestMapping annotation and mvc is annotation driven. I am also using MappingJackson2Json as default views

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```
@Override
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public Response<?> beforeBodyWrite(Response<?> body, MethodParameter returnType,
                                   MediaType selectedContentType,
                                   Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
                                   ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {

                ....

    return body;
}
```

Comment: How would changing return type of beforeBodyWrite to Response<?> from object matter ?

Comment: may the following link help you find a solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884737/controlleradvice-not-firing

Comment: When I write any method annotated with `@InitBinder` or `@ExceptionHandler` then it's working fine, but `@ExceptionHandler` is only called when exception is thrown and `@initBinder` is called before controller is executed. My requirement is to call this method after every controller is executed not just when exception is thrown.

Comment: Try the HandlerInterceptor interface. 
HandlerInterceptor interface defines the following methods:
§ preHandle – this method is executed before the controller processes the request.  
§ postHandle – this method is executed after the controller processes the request,
but before the view is rendered by the DispatcherServlet.
§ afterCompletion – this method is invoked after the completion of request processing (that is, after the view is rendered by the DispatcherServlet) to do any cleanup, if required.

Comment: Here an concrete example: http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-handlerinterceptor-annotation-example-webmvcconfigureradapter

Comment: I had tried using `@postHandle` of HandlerInterceptor, but it's also not working. I also read some docs where it's mentioned that `@postHandle` doesn't work well with `@ResponseBody`

Comment: Note that the postHandle method of HandlerInterceptor is not always ideally suited for use with @ResponseBody and ResponseEntity methods. In such cases an HttpMessageConverter writes to and commits the response before `postHandle` is called which makes it impossible to change the response, for example to add a header. Instead an application can implement `ResponseBodyAdvice` and either declare it as an `@ControllerAdvice` bean or configure it directly on RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.